# Chapter bibliography using subfiles

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib, subfiles

**Introduction**

I am writing a report consisting of several assignments for one of my university courses. My OS is Windows and I use TeXstudio as editor. I am using the `subfiles` package as I want to have separate files for each assignment, being able to compile each file independently and finally assemble everything in one unique document that I have to deliver. I am using a custom class derived from the `report` class so that each assignment constitutes a `chapter` of the document and thus each subfile contains a single `chapter`.

**Problem**

I would like each `chapter` to have its own bibliography (and **no** global bibliography), included in the corresponding subfile. However this has become a nightmare, since I have tried different solutions with little success. A complication of my situation is given by the fact that I use the `minted` package to display some code. Of course I need to invoke the `-shell-escape` flag in TeXstudio, but this seems to interfere with the generation of `.bbl` file when compiling the subfile.

An explanation of my attempts follows and at the end of the question you can find a MWE including all attempted approaches.

**Attempted solutions**

- **`natbib`+`chapterbib` approach**: inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341975/133079) (where however `\include` is used instead of `\subfile`). If the `minted` package is **not** used, compiling subfile works (even if weird stuff appears in the bibliography, probably due to the style chosen) but when the main file is compiled the entire bibliography is repeated for each chapter, whereas only the chapter-related bibliography should appear.

`chapter1.tex` output:

[image]

`main.tex` output:

[image]

If the `minted` package is used, no `.bbl` file is generated when both `chapter1.tex` and `main.tex` are compiled.

`chapter1.tex` output:

[image]

- **`natbib`+`bibunits` approach**: inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353746/133079), the output when compiling the subfile is the same whether `minted` is in use or not. However, if `minted` is used, no `.bbl` file at all is generated, instead if `minted` is not used the `chapter1.bbl` file is generated, but apparently a `bu1.bbl` file is missing.

`chapter1.tex` output:

[image]

- **`biblatex` approach**: inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44590/133079) (where however there is no use of `subfiles` package). This attempt makes use of the `refsection` feature of `biblatex`. The output when compiling the subfile is the same whether `minted` is in use or not: the bibliography items are recognized but the bibliography itself is not printed. It is quite curious that if `minted` is used, no `.bbl` file at all is generated, instead if `minted` is not used the `chapter1.bbl` file appears in the folder.

`chapter1.tex` output:

[image]

**Project structure and MWE**

All approaches are reported in the codes listed, you can switch from one approach to the other by toggling the corresponding lines in both the main and the subfile. You will notice that I have both a `bibgraf.bib` file at the level of `main.tex` and `bibgraf1.bib`, `bibgraf2.bib` files at the level of the corresponding chapters. The former includes all bibliography items, while the latters only the chapter-related items. I do not have any preference regarding the approaches (packages to use, one main root `.bib` file or multiple `.bib` files for each chapter, etc.) I would just like to have each chapter with its corresponding bibliography within the subfile.

```
-project
    -main.tex
    -bibgraf.bib
    -chapter1
        -chapter1.tex
        -bibgraf1.bib
    -chapter2
        -chapter2.tex
        -bibgraf2.bib
```

`main.tex`

```
% Definition of main command to access subfiles input both from master and slave files
\providecommand{\main}{.}

% Document class
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel} % management of culturally-determined typographical (and other) rules for the document language

% Package to generate code listing
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
% newfloat: the float package is used to create the listing environment

% Subfiles package
\usepackage{subfiles}

% Bibliography packages
%---- Natbib + chapterbib approach -----
%\usepackage[sectionbib,super,sort]{natbib}
%\usepackage{chapterbib}
%---------------------------------------
%---- Natbib + bibunit approach -----
%\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
%\usepackage{bibunits}
%\defaultbibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
%------------------------------------
%---- Biblatex approach -----
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibgraf.bib}
%----------------------------

% Change chapter name
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Assignment}}

\begin{document}

    This is something from the main

    % First chapter
    \subfile{chapter1/chapter1}

    % Second chapter
    \subfile{chapter2/chapter2}

\end{document}
```

`bibgraf.bib`

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="00",editor="1",pages="1",title="0",year="0"}

@article{Kulfan2008,
    author = {Kulfan, B. M.},
    title = {Universal Parametric Geometry Representation Method},
    journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
    volume = {45},
    number = {1},
    pages = {142-158},
    year = {2008},
    doi = {10.2514/1.29958},
    URL = { 
    https://doi.org/10.2514/1.29958
    },
    eprint = { 
    https://doi.org/10.2514/1.29958
    }
}

@book{anderson,
    title={Fundamental of Aerodynamics},
    author={Anderson, Jr., J. D.},
    isbn={9781259010286},
    series={McGraw-Hill Series in Aeronautical and Aerospace engineering},
    url={https://books.google.nl/books?id=xVsiAwAAQBAJ},
    year={2011},
    edition={5},
    publisher={McGraw-Hill}
}

@book{abbott,
    title={Theory of Wing Sections},
    subtitle={Including a Symmary of Airfoil Data},
    author={Abbott, I. H. and von Doenhoff, A. E.},
    isbn={9780486605869},
    series={Dover Books on Aeronautical Engineering Series},
    year={1959},
    publisher={Dover Pubblications}
}
```

`chapter1.tex`

```
%!TeX root = chapter1

\providecommand{\main}{..}

\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{\main/}}
\makeatother

\documentclass[\main/main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

    %---- Natbib + bibunit approach -----
%   \begin{bibunit}
%       \chapter{First chapter}
%       This is chapter 1 reference test: \cite{Kulfan2008}, \cite{anderson}.
%       \subsection*{References}
%       \putbib[\main/chapter1/bibgraf1]
%   \end{bibunit}
    %------------------------------------

    %---- Natbib + chapterbib approach -----
%   \chapter{First chapter}
%   This is chapter 1 reference test: \cite{Kulfan2008}, \cite{anderson}.
%   \nocite{apsrev41Control}
%   \bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
%   \bibliography{\main/bibgraf}
    %---------------------------------------

    %--------- Biblatex approach ----------
    \newrefsection
    \chapter{First chapter}
    This is chapter 1 reference test: \autocite{Kulfan2008}, \autocite{anderson}.
    \printbibliography
    %--------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

`bibgraf1.bib`

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="00",editor="1",pages="1",title="0",year="0"}

@article{Kulfan2008,
    author = {Kulfan, B. M.},
    title = {Universal Parametric Geometry Representation Method},
    journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
    volume = {45},
    number = {1},
    pages = {142-158},
    year = {2008},
    doi = {10.2514/1.29958},
    URL = { 
    https://doi.org/10.2514/1.29958
    },
    eprint = { 
    https://doi.org/10.2514/1.29958
    }
}

@book{anderson,
    title={Fundamental of Aerodynamics},
    author={Anderson, Jr., J. D.},
    isbn={9781259010286},
    series={McGraw-Hill Series in Aeronautical and Aerospace engineering},
    url={https://books.google.nl/books?id=xVsiAwAAQBAJ},
    year={2011},
    edition={5},
    publisher={McGraw-Hill}
}
```

`chapter2.tex`

```
%!TeX root = chapter2

\providecommand{\main}{..}

\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{\main/}}
\makeatother

\documentclass[\main/main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

    %---- Natbib + bibunit approach -----
%   \begin{bibunit}
%       \chapter{Second chapter}
%       This is chapter 2 reference test: \cite{Kulfan2008}, \cite{abbott}.
%       \subsection*{References}
%       \putbib[\main/chapter2/bibgraf2]
%   \end{bibunit}
    %------------------------------------

    %---- Natbib + chapterbib approach -----
%   \chapter{Second chapter}
%   This is chapter 2 reference test: \cite{Kulfan2008}, \cite{abbott}.
%   \nocite{apsrev41Control}
%   \bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
%   \bibliography{\main/bibgraf}
    %---------------------------------------

    %--------- Biblatex approach ----------
    \newrefsection
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    This is chapter 2 reference test: \autocite{Kulfan2008}, \autocite{abbott}.
    \printbibliography
    %--------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

`bibgraf2.bib`

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="00",editor="1",pages="1",title="0",year="0"}

@article{Kulfan2008,
    author = {Kulfan, B. M.},
    title = {Universal Parametric Geometry Representation Method},
    journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
    volume = {45},
    number = {1},
    pages = {142-158},
    year = {2008},
    doi = {10.2514/1.29958},
    URL = { 
    https://doi.org/10.2514/1.29958
    },
    eprint = { 
    https://doi.org/10.2514/1.29958
    }
}

@book{abbott,
    title={Theory of Wing Sections},
    subtitle={Including a Symmary of Airfoil Data},
    author={Abbott, I. H. and von Doenhoff, A. E.},
    isbn={9780486605869},
    series={Dover Books on Aeronautical Engineering Series},
    year={1959},
    publisher={Dover Pubblications}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sub-bibliographies work with `subfiles` from version 1.5 onwards, available from [Github](https://github.com/gsalzer/subfiles) or from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles). See its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf). Note that it is no longer necessary to manipulate the path of files oneself. Below I show how to typeset sub-bibliographies with package

**(A)** `chapterbib`

**(B)** `bibunits`

**(C)** `biblatex`

For each of these scenarios, we consider two file structures.

**(1)** bib files in the top directory

```
main.tex
bib1.bib
bib2.bib
chapter1/chapter1.tex
chapter2/chapter2.tex
```

**(2)** bib files in the subdirectories

```
main.tex
chapter1/bib1.bib
chapter1/chapter1.tex
chapter2/bib2.bib
chapter2/chapter2.tex
```

The bib files contain the following entries.

```
% bib1.bib
@book{A,
    title={The meaning of A},
    author={A. Alpha},
    year=2019,
    publisher={Apublisher}
}

% bib2.bib
@book{B,
    title={The meaning of B},
    author={B. Beta},
    year=2019,
    publisher={Bpublisher}
}
```

### (A1) Package `chapterbib`, bib files in main directory

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfileinclude{chapter1/chapter1}
\subfileinclude{chapter2/chapter2}
\end{document}    

% chapter1/chapter1.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
My references: \cite{A}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{../bib1,../bib2}
\end{document}

% chapter2/chapter2.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Second chapter}
My references: \cite{B}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{../bib1,../bib2}
\end{document}
```

To typeset `main.tex`, run

```
pdflatex main
bibtex chapter1/chapter1
bibtex chapter2/chapter2
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

To typeset one of the chapters separately, run

```
cd chapter1
pdflatex chapter1
bibtex chapter1
pdflatex chapter1
pdflatex chapter1
```

### (A2) Package `chapterbib`, bib files in sub-directory

Like (A1), but change the `\bibliography` commands to `\bibliography{bib1}` in `chapter1.tex` and to `\bibliography{bib2}` in `chapter2.tex`.

### (B1) Package `bibunits`, bib files in main directory

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\defaultbibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1/chapter1}
\subfile{chapter2/chapter2}
\end{document}

% chapter1/chapter1.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{bibunit}
\chapter{First chapter}
My references: \cite{A}
\putbib[\subfix{../bib1},\subfix{../bib2}]
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}

% chapter2/chapter2.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{bibunit}
\chapter{Second chapter}
My references: \cite{B}
\putbib[\subfix{../bib1},\subfix{../bib2}]
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

To typeset the main document, run

```
pdflatex main
bibtex bu1
bibtex bu2
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

To typeset the chapters separately, run

```
cd chapter1
pdflatex chapter1
bibtex bu1
pdflatex chapter1
pdflatex chapter1
```

### (B2) Package `bibunits`, bib files in sub-directory

Like (B1), but change the `\putbib` commands to `\putbib[\subfix{bib1}]` in `chapter1.tex` and to `\putbib[\subfix{bib2}]` in `chapter2.tex`.

### (C1) Package `biblatex`, bib files in main directory

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\bibliography{bib1,bib2}
\begin{document}
\subfileinclude{chapter1/chapter1}
\subfileinclude{chapter2/chapter2}
\end{document}

% chapter1/chapter1.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\newrefsection
\chapter{First chapter}
My references: \cite{A}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

% chapter2/chapter2.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\newrefsection
\chapter{Second chapter}
My references: \cite{B}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

To typeset the main document, run

```
pdflatex main
biber main
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

To typeset the chapters separately, run

```
cd chapter1
pdflatex chapter1
biber chapter1
pdflatex chapter1
pdflatex chapter1
```

### (C2) Package `biblatex`, bib files in sub-directory

Like (C1), but replace the `\bibliography` command in `main.tex` by `\bibliography{chapter1/bib1,chapter2/bib2}`.

### Note on filenames and their paths

In general, filenames (with an optional path) have to be surrounded by `\subfix{...}`, as demonstrated in (B1) and (B2). The `\bibliography` command has this `\subfix` magic already built-in, therefore `\subfix` is not needed in (A1), (A2), (C1) and (C2) (in fact, it rather would mess up things).

Comment: Is there any way to have the bibliography files live in the chapter subdirectories? And ideally, for each of them to be able to *only* reference their "own" bib file? I.e., `\bibliography{bib1}` in `chapter1/chapter1.tex`

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I have redone my answer from 2019. It now discusses your situation as well.

Comment: thanks! I actually figured it out, but it's good to see it corroborated. Note that you accidentally call your `bib` files `*.tex`, and also that I think you need to run `pdflatex` on each of the chapter files (from their own directories) to create the `aux` files before you can run BibTeX.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe Thanks for the note regarding file extensions, I've corrected them. Because of the `\include` statements (instead of `\input`), LaTeX generates separate `aux` files for the included files. I've actually tested all versions (with the correct extensions).

Comment: Yep, exactly right about not needing the `pdflatex` runs -- that was a holdover from my attempts to use plain `\subfile` instead of `\subfileinclude`, which I could never get to work...

Comment: Now the only problem is that this setup doesn't appear to work in [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com)...

Comment: Overleaf uses an older version of `subfiles` (and of TeX alltogether), which should work as well (and indeed works in my test environment). I tried to copy it to Overleaf, but have difficulties to tell it to run latex/bibtex/... on the right files in the right order. Giving up ...

Comment: I have to use `\subfix` in all (C) cases. I use `\printbibliography` at the end of the main file.